# Datatables 1.10 paging only shows page number 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using jQuery DataTables v1.10.
At our new website we have a dataset with more than 10000 records.
The displayLength is set by default at 50 records.

After initializing the DataTable, 50 of 10000+ records are showing, but there's only 1 pagination item visible and a forward and backward arrow which are both disabled.

When I'm changing the displayLength to 100, I get one page with 100 records out of 10000+, but still one page instead of more than 100 pages.

This is our initialisation:

```
"oLanguage": oDatatablesNL,
    "sDom": '<"dt-toolbar clearfix"fpl>rt<"row-actions"><"dt-toolbar bottom clearfix"p>',
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/?async=yes&get=datatable,
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[ 4, "asc" ]],
    "paging": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "displayStart": 0,
    "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500], [50, 100, 500]],
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    //"deferRender": true,
    "columns":
    [
        { 
            "data": "firstColumn",
            "class": "first"
        },
        { 
            "data": "secondColumn",
            "class": "second"
        },
    ],
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        dtUpdateData(row, data, dataIndex);
    },
    "initComplete": function() {
        dtExtras(dtLengths);
    }
```

And our serverside data:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":"15827","recordsFiltered":"50","data":[{'column1':'test','column2':'test2'}]
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem seemed to be that recordsFiltered should be the number of records which were filtered by the query. I've searched for the answer during more than 2 hours; feeling really dumb now... ;)

Comment: Don't feel bad, the documentation is pretty confusing and fooled me too. https://datatables.net/faqs/

Comment: Still valid for V4.x maybe not so clear the difference between `recordsFiltered` and  `recordsTotal`